# How to back to className when menu is hide

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I would like to make mobile menu witch changing background color and height from(10% to 100%. When menu is active nav—active hover all page for darkening)

```
const nav = document.getElementById("navigation");
const burger = document.getElementById("mobileBurger");
const menu = document.getElementById("mobileMenu");

burger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.classList.toggle("nav--active");

  if (nav.classList.contains("nav--scroll")) {
    nav.classList.remove("nav--scroll");
  }

  console.log(nav.classList.contains("nav"));
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  let scrolled = window.pageYOffset;

  if (scrolled >= 40) {
    nav.classList.add("nav--scroll");
  } else nav.classList.remove("nav--scroll");
});
```

When nav is „nav—scrolled”, and I click on button, then I would like to leave only class=„nav nav—active”. Ok I did this, but how to back to „nav—scrolled” after hide menu. Of course only when it had this class?

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at it for you, but the html would be helpful to test it.
Notice moved the scroll check to a separate function to call when needed.

```js
const nav = document.getElementById("navigation");
const burger = document.getElementById("mobileBurger");
const menu = document.getElementById("mobileMenu");

burger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // toggle returns a true or false based on if it adds/removes
  if( nav.classList.toggle("nav--active") == false) {
    // if it added (made inactive), lets check and see if scroll also applies.
    checkScrolled();
  } else {
    if (nav.classList.contains("nav--scroll")) {
      nav.classList.remove("nav--scroll");
    }
  }

  console.log(nav.classList.contains("nav"));
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  checkScrolled();
});

function checkScrolled() {
    let scrolled = window.pageYOffset;

  if (scrolled >= 40 && nav.classList.contains("nav--scroll") == false) {
    nav.classList.add("nav--scroll");
  } else { 
    nav.classList.remove("nav--scroll"); 
  }
}
```